# R modify an element matrix in csv file

Tags: r, csv, matrix, element

I think my question is not very complicated but i don't find solution.
I want to modify just a element of a matrix in a csv format. 
I use the write.table command for write the matrix but i don't know how change the element A[i,j] and not rewrite all the matrix. For example if i use the code below all the matrix is rewrite and not just the element A[2,2].

```
 A<- rbind(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6),c(7,8,9))
 A
 [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    2    3
 [2,]    4    5    6
 [3,]    7    8    9
 write.table(A, file = "A.csv", sep = "\t", col.names =T, row.names =T)
 #I modify 2 elements of matrix
 A[2,2]<-0
 A[1,1]<-0
 A
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    0    2    3
 [2,]    4    0    6
 [3,]    7    8    9
 write.table(A[2,2], file = "A.csv", sep = "\t", col.names =T,
```

Of course the code below print just the element A[2,2]

```
 write.table(A[2,2], file = "A.csv", sep = "\t", col.names =T,     row.names=T)
```

But i would like just modify the element A[2,2] in the csv file
Thanks for help

Comment: You can't just modify part of the file; you need to overwrite the existing file with the updated data. Just run `write.table(A, file = "A.csv", sep = "\t", col.names =T, row.names =T)` again after you've modified the `A` matrix.

Comment: You can look at `seek` as an option to reach into specific location of the file (assuming fixed width formatted file) and see if that works in your case. Read the manual page first though with `?seek`

Comment: MrFlick thanks, of course for this code I can rewrite the file after the line A[2,2]<-0 but this it's a part of code more longer where this solution can't be used.
Gopala, I don't know the command seek I investigate in this way,.
Thanks